# Register Extensions automatically in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I am *extending* JUnit's `ParameterResolver` to provide a custom argument in Test methods.

```
 public class MyParameterResolver implements ParameterResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext,
            ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return parameterContext.getParameter().getType() == MyWrapper.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext,
            ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {

        // Do something about getting MyAnnotation

        return new MyWrapper();
    }

}
```

and then using it in test methods using `ExtendWith`

```
@ExtendWith(MyParameterResolver.class)
@Test
@MyAnnotation(val = 20)
@MyAnnotation(val = 30)    
void test(MyWrapper wrapper) {
    System.out.println(wrapper);
}
```

It works perfectly however I do not like the idea that all the tests which needs this extension would need to be annotated with `@ExtendWith(MyParameterResolver.class)` , is it possible to automatically register the annotation in Junit programmatically whenever a test method contains `MyWrapper` parameter or `MyAnnotation` annotation?

Answer (score 4):

[§5.2 of the *JUnit 5 User Guide*](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration) shows the three ways one can register extensions:

1. Declaratively with `@ExtendWith` ([§5.2.1](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative)).

   > Developers can register one or more extensions *declaratively* by annotating a test interface, test class, test method, or custom [*composed annotation*](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations) with `@ExtendWith(…​)` and supplying class references for the extensions to register.

   <sup>***Note:** If you annotate the class with `@ExtendWith(...)` then all enclosed test methods will be extended by the specified extension.*</sup>
2. Programmatically with `@RegisterExtension` ([§5.2.2](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic)).

   > Developers can register extensions *programmatically* by annotating fields in test classes with [`@RegisterExtension`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/RegisterExtension.html).
   >
   > When an extension is registered *declaratively* via `@ExtendWith`, it can typically only be configured via annotations. In contrast, when an extension is registered via `@RegisterExtension`, it can be configured *programmatically* — for example, in order to pass arguments to the extension’s constructor, a static factory method, or a builder API.
3. Automatically via `java.util.ServiceLoader` ([§5.2.3](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic)).

   > In addition to declarative extension registration and programmatic extension registration support using annotations, JUnit Jupiter also supports *global extension registration* via Java’s `java.util.ServiceLoader` mechanism, allowing third-party extensions to be auto-detected and automatically registered based on what is available in the classpath.
   >
   > Specifically, a custom extension can be registered by supplying its fully qualified class name in a file named `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension` within the `/META-INF/services` folder in its enclosing JAR file.

   <sup>***Note:** Automatic registration [must be explicitly enabled](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic-enabling).*</sup>

If you're okay with your extension being registered globally then you can use the automatic registration mechanism. But there does not appear to be a way to only extend test methods if they have a specific parameter type. However, you may be able to create a so-called *composed annotation* to make things simpler:

```java
@ExtendWith(MyParameterResolver.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface ComposedAnnotation {

  int[] vals(); // int array to (maybe?) replace the multiple @MyAnnotation(val = XXX) annotations
}
```

Though I don't know if that's compatible with your `@MyAnnotation` annotation.

Note that if your implementation of `#supportsParameter(ParameterContext,ExtensionContext)` is quick then having the extension registered for methods which don't use it should not be a problem. In other words, it won't significantly slow down your tests or, as far as I know, cause errors.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If you see JUnit's behavior for `TestReporterParameterResolver` , it automatically registers it in `MutableExtensionRegistry` whenever a test method contains the parameter `TestReporter` . I am looking for similar way to register the extension automatically. If you see my question description, I am already using #1 approach, and #2 is pretty much same as #1 that test classes will require the manual line to register.

Comment: I'm just listing all three possible ways to register extensions, as documented—that includes what you're already doing (though I do mention you could annotate the class instead of each method individually or that you could _possibly_ use a composed annotation depending on what exactly you need). The `TestReporterParameterResolver` extension is built-in and is therefore handled specially; however, from the point-of-view of the developer, that extension is registered as if by approach #3.